# Chart.js bar chart : Grid color and hide label

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to change to background color of my grid in chart.js, I've tried following the documentation and I've done a lot of research but I can't seem to figure it out. I also want to get rid of the top label, can't find an easy way to do that either. The label I'm talking about is the label that says "My first dataset" on the demo here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart

Solution:

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "",
    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4],
    backgroundColor: "rgba(3, 118, 195, 0.5)",
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 158, 219, 1)",
    borderWidth: "2",
  }]
},
options: {
  legend:{
      display: false
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
            show: true,
            color: "F3F3F3",
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  },

}
  });

</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To hide lable i.e nothing but legend:
Use below config in `options`:

```
legend:{
       display:false
}
```

Thus in your code:

```
options: {
    legend:{
           display:false
    },  
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
```

And, for background color use css for canvas element:

```
<canvas id="myChart" style="background-color: grey;">
```

Hope this will do for you!

Comment: But I was trying to recolor the grid, so the lines on the background any idea on how that works? Thanks!

Comment: For background grid line color:

 scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    show: true,
                    color: "red",
                    }
            }]
        }

Similarly for Y-axis

Comment: Thanks so much, the answer worked perfectly. I accepted your answer as I just got enough reputation!